# iMac does not get online, but will through Parallels

Tags: networking

We have a iMac that is getting a connection to the network, but refuses to ping or get online from any browser. HOWEVER, if I use Parallels (VM Software) the Windows install will get online.

Can't figure it out. Any suggestions as to why the iMac is refusing to connect natively, but will connect through Windows on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

If your VM is in bridged mode, then it is like an independent device on your network. What's good is that it shows that your NIC isn't dead.

You should look in System Preferences and make sure that you don't have any static IPs/DNS/Gateways set. Set everything to DHCP/Auto and see if you have better luck.

Comment: All those settings were set, and flushed, and reset. Eventually I just ended up doing a re-install. That worked.